# Update by referring foreign key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, one-to-one

Password already been exist in Passw Model/Table. Here i want to change my password.

I want to update using regist_id(foreign key), not by Id in table passw.

Controller:

```
$passw = Passw::whereRegist_id($id)->get();       //Regist_id is an foregin key
$regist->pass()->update([
                    'password1' => $request->newpassword,
                    'password2' => $request->newpassword1
                ]);
return view('welcome');
```

Regist Model:

```
public function pass(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Passw');
}
```

When i give update it redirect to welcome page. But not password value been changed.

Where am i do mistake.

Comment: Have you checked if $passw->id & $reg->pass->id is the same?

Comment: what is the relation between `Passw` and `Regist` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update it like this

```
$passw = Passw::where('regist_id', $id)->first();

$passw->update([
                 'password1' => $request->newpassword,
                 'password2' => $request->newpassword1
              ]);
```

You can fetch `Regist` model using `$id`

```
$regist = Regist::with('pass')->find($id);

$regist->pass->update([
         'password1' => $request->newpassword,
         'password2' => $request->newpassword1
]);
```

Comment: I try to do update using one-to-one relation, also update refer by foreign key. Can i do here?